# Determine $\sigma(A)$ for $A=\{\{x\}|x\in\Omega\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We had the following exercise in our exam and I am interested in a solution.

Let $\Omega$ be a set and $A=\{\{x\}\mid x\in\Omega\}$. Determine $\sigma(A)$.

I think $\sigma(A)=\{D\subset \Omega: D\textrm{ countable or }D^c\textrm{ countable}\}$.

So $\supset$ is obvious.
For $\subset$ I've showed that the right side is a $\sigma$-algebra and "$A\subset\textrm{right side}$". This proved my claim.

But what about finite sets $D$?

Comment: Does your definition of countable sets include finite sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If countable means infinite and countable your answer should be $\{D \subset \Omega: D \text{ finite or countable or } D^c \text{ finite or countable}\}$. With only countable you cannot show it is a $\sigma$-algebra, as these are also closed under *finite* unions and intersections...

The rest of the argument is OK.